# VBS - how to convert ":" on "-"

Tags: vbscript, expression

I have:

```
sFilmNamePl = oInternetExplorer.Document.getElementsByClassName("filmMainHeader")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innerHTML
```

***result:***
Mission: Comando

but i want:
**Misiion - Comando**

how to convert ":" on "-"

Regular expressions can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for regular expressions

```
sFilmNamePl = Replace(sFilmNamePl, ":", "-")
```